# Are nullptr references undefined behaviour in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, undefined-behavior, nullptr

The following code fools around with `nullptr` pointer and reference:

```
#include <cstdio>

void printRefAddr(int &ref) {
    printf("printAddr %p\n", &ref);
}

int main() {    
    int *ip = nullptr;
    int &ir = *ip;

    // 1. get address of nullptr reference
    printf("ip=%p &ir=%p\n", ip, &ir);

    // 2. dereference a nullptr pointer and pass it as reference
    printRefAddr(*ip);

    // 3. pass nullptr reference
    printRefAddr(ir);

    return 0;
}
```

**Question**: In C++ standards, are commented statements 1..3 valid code or undefined behavior?

Is this same or different with different versions of C++ (older ones would of course use `0` literal instead of `nullptr` keyword)?

Bonus question: are there known compilers / optimization options, which would actually cause above code to do something unexpected / crash? For example, is there a flag for any compiler, which would generate implicit assertion for `nullptr` everywhere where reference is initialized, including passing reference argument from `*ptr`?

---

An example output for the curious, nothing unexpected:

```
ip=(nil) &ir=(nil)
printAddr (nil)
printAddr (nil)
```

Comment: null pointer references have always been UB. have you searched?

Comment: You get UB way before (1) already, when you dereference `ip` the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `// 2. dereference a nullptr pointer and pass it as reference`

Dereferencing a null pointer is **Undefined Behaviour**, and so whether you pass it as a reference or by value, the fact is that you've dereferenced it and therefore invoked UB, meaning from that point on all bets are off.

You've already invoked UB here:

```
int &ir = *ip; //ip is null, you cannot deref it without invoking UB.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `ir` is just a shadow of `*ip` it will not cause an undefined behavior on its own.

The undefined behavior is using a pointer which points to `nullptr_t`. I mean using `*ip`. Therefore

```
int &ir = *ip;
          ^^^
```

Causes an UB.